# Android complex expand activity transition

Tags: android, animation, transition, expand

So I have been trying to reproduce this particular animation for a day now :

http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/animations-meaningfultransitions-hierarchical_transitions_topLevel_large_xhdpi.webm

But I can't figure out how to make it, because I think that I don't get the way this transition is performed.

The main problem is the expanding part from the imageView that leads to the other activity.

Here is how I have approached the whole animation:

I have tried to move the imageView like this :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and then use a shared elements transition at the end of the first animation:

```
@Override
        public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

            View sharedView = imageView;
            ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, sharedView, "image");
            startActivity(i, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
        }
```

But I can't figure how to expand the imageView to launch the next activity, as the shared elements transition launches the activity in a basic way. 
I maybe could expand the second layout after the activity is launched, but the effect would be way less impressive.

If you have any ideas on how to make this expand transition, please let me know

Comment: check this link http://jimulabs.com/2014/12/journey-lollipop-transitions-part-1/ in lollipop 3 new activity transtion were included

Comment: This doesn't give me the answer for the expanding activity... I really want the activity to be entered by expanding content below the shared image, and I cannot figure how to do that..